# C# save file so that the output is multi-lines

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2022, savefiledialog

I'm trying my first attempt at a "Save file" button.
It's going surprisingly well. :D
I have been able to get the file to combine multiple pieces of user-inputted text from different text-boxes into a single file and save it as a text file output.

Where I am stuck is that I'm trying to figure out how to split the text file into multiple lines for easier readability. I have tried searching for examples online, but everything I'm seeing shows the opposite, how to combine multiple text inputs into a single file. I've already got that.

Here's my code. I'm trying to break it into new lines where the long empty spaces are.
Thanks in advance.

```
private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
        sfd.FileName = "Writing Prompt- " + Txt_Prompt_Title.Text;
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path = sfd.FileName;
           TextWriter sf = new StreamWriter (File.Create(path));
            sf.Write("Writing Prompt: " + Txt_Prompt_Title.Text +  "        " + Lbl_Prompt_Output.Text + "           " + Txt_Prompt_Notes.Text);
            sf.Dispose();

        }
    }
```

Comment: textwriter has a `WriteLine` function for this exact purpose

Comment: advices: 1) I'd use  File.AppendAllText("filename", $"{Txt_Prompt_Title.Text} 
   {Lbl_Prompt_Output.Text}    {Txt_Prompt_Notes.Text}"); to write all content within a file ;  2) Pay attention to use a Text property to set name to file it coulbe too long; 3) could you set to true a MultipleLine all Textboxes and use them  with .Text property directly to popolate file content like indicate in point 1

Comment: Replace your long empty spaces with `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: @pm100 I though "Writeline" was just for Console applications?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.writeline?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
 private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
        sfd.FileName = "Writing Prompt- " + Txt_Prompt_Title.Text;
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path = sfd.FileName;
           TextWriter sf = new StreamWriter (File.Create(path));
            sf.Write("Writing Prompt: " + Txt_Prompt_Title.Text + 
                "\n" + 
                "\n " + Lbl_Prompt_Output.Text + 
                "\n" +
                "\n " + Txt_Prompt_Notes.Text);
            sf.Dispose();

        }
    }
```

Comment: `.WriteLine` would use the correct line endings for the environment it's running in, and you should have a `using` scope around the writer, to ensure proper disposal in case of an exception.

Comment: It's equally important that you declare the `SaveFileDialog` with a using statement. That too really needs to be disposed. -- Not clear why you declare `sf` as `TextWriter`. Just `using (var sf = new StreamWriter(...)`)

Comment: @Jimi ...let's pretend that I'm totally new to this and I don't understand anything you said just now. ...in fact, let's not pretend. :D   I thought "Using" only went way up at the top, like Using System.IO?  Are you saying that there should be "using" down here in this block also? I declared it as "Textwriter" because that's what the tutorials I've been following did. I recognize that this might not be the most-correct way to do it, I just don't know what I don't know, you know?

Comment: :) 1) You're referring to a [`using` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive),  
Mathieu Guindon
 and I referred to a [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement), which is used to declare an object that is the automatically disposed of when code execution exists the `using` block. 2) `TextWriter` it the abstract class, you don't want or need that. Use the actual object you have just declared, a `StreamWriter`.

Comment: @Jimi, thank you for that explanation. I think I understand that part now.

Comment: You're welcome :) Errata corrige: in *when code execution exists the `using` block*, ***exists*** is obviously **exits**.

Comment: @JohnathanClayborn Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a restatement of the OP's self-answer, incorporating the suggestions that were made in the comments.  I'm also using the orginal `using` syntax, not everyone is using a recent compiler.  If the OP updates his/her answer, I'll delete this:

```
private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var sfd = new SaveFileDialog()) {
        sfd.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
        sfd.FileName = "Writing Prompt- " + Txt_Prompt_Title.Text;
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path = sfd.FileName;
            using (var sf = new StreamWriter (File.Create(path))){
                sf.Write("Writing Prompt: " + Txt_Prompt_Title.Text + 
                "\n" + 
                "\n " + Lbl_Prompt_Output.Text + 
                "\n" +
                "\n " + Txt_Prompt_Notes.Text);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

What I didn't add was code that uses `Environment.Newline` instead of `"\n"`, or code that gets rid of the string concatenation (which can cause a lot of *garbage* string objects that need to be *garbage collected*).  One way to achieve both would be to use `.WriteLine` over and over again, as @MathieuGuindon suggests).

You probably want to look up [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation) for creating strings that have the string rendering of other objects embedded in them.

You should really follow the link to the [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) that @jimi has pointed you to.  It provides a way to make sure you properly `Dispose` of objects that implement `IDisposable` while making your code more readable.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is definitely cleaner than I had it originally. I will definitely look into String Interpolation and try to learn more about that.